# composor manager stability setting

Tags: 7, composer

I am trying to install some packages using composer manager. My installation failed reflecting the following error:

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name 
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.

I have tried to change setting in my composer file 'composer_manager.api.php' but it didnt give any result except the error mentioned above. Is there a different file where i can change the settings?
I can add extra details if needed.

Please help me in sorting this.

Thanks,
Chaithanya.

Comment: The documentation for that module mentions nothing about a `composer_manager.api.php` file...why are you putting settings in that file exactly? All settings should go in the composer.json file, no?

Comment: I did not find any configuration settings to change in composer.json file though..The only settings I could find were in the file mentioned above.

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention anything to do with an 'api' file though, so I'm not sure where you've got the idea to use a file with that specific name. Is there some extra documentation for the module that's not linked to from the main page or something?